# error CS1729: 'Vector3' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Tags: unity-game-engine

I keep trying to catch what I did wrong but I can't. Can someone help me? It says that

> ```
> error CS1729: 'Vector3' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments.
> ```

My code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0.5f)
        {
            transform.Translate(new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is clear, you cant just do say new Vector3(1.2f) .. you need 3 arguments.

Answer (score 2):

[The `Vector3` struct in `System.Numerics`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector3) does indeed have a constructor which accepts a single `float` as an argument.  (Which internally applies that one value to all three properties of the vector.)

However, you're not using `System.Numerics` in your code.  It looks like `UnityEngine` has a different [`Vector3` struct](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html).  And it has [only one constructor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-ctor.html):

```
public Vector3(float x, float y, float z);
```

So to use it you'll need to supply all three values being used in the vector.  Perhaps you meant to separate the values instead of multiply them?:

```
new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), moveSpeed, Time.deltaTime)
```

If you meant something else then you'd need to define the values you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

Vector 3 takes 3 arguments. X, Y and Z value. You just need to put that Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime) in the x position like this
Transform.Translate(new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0))